# Removing structs from array

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to implement a function that loops through a sorted array of structs and if the "key" (the first field value) has a duplicate, it will keep the first iteration of that key-value pair, and remove any duplicates that come after. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Map * collect_values(int n, int *arr);
void sort_values(struct Map *ptr, int n);
void print(struct Map *print_struct, int n);
struct Map * remove_duplicates(struct Map *ptr, int n);

struct Map{
    int value, position;
};

int compare(const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2){
    const struct Map *aptr = ptr1;
    const struct Map *bptr = ptr2;

    if(aptr->value == bptr->value){
        return (aptr->position > bptr->position) - 
(aptr->position < bptr->position);
    }
    else{
        return (aptr->value > bptr->value) - (aptr->value < bptr->value);
    }
}

int compare2(const void *aptr, const void *bptr){
    int a = ((struct Map*)aptr)->position, b = ((struct 
Map*)bptr)->position;
    return (a > b) - (a < b);
}

int main(){
    int size, i;
    scanf("%d", &size);
    int *arr = (int*) malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    struct Map *p = collect_values(size,arr);
    printf("Struct before sorting:\n");
    print(p,size);
    qsort(p,size,sizeof(struct Map),compare);
    printf("Struct after sorting\n");
    print(p,size);
    struct Map *p2 = remove_duplicates(p,size);
    printf("\nStruct after removing in the main\n");

    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(*p2); i++){
         printf("%d : %d\n", p2[i].value, p2[i].position);
    }
    free(p);
    free(arr);
    free(p2);
    return 0;
 }

struct Map * collect_values(int n, int *arr){
    int i, position = 0;
    struct Map *array = calloc(n,sizeof(*array));
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
        array[i].value = arr[i];
        array[i].position = position;
        position++;
    }
    return array;

}

void print(struct Map * print_struct, int n){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("%d : %d\n", print_struct[i].value, print_struct[i].position);
    }
}

struct Map * remove_duplicates(struct Map *ptr, int n){
    int i, j = 0, newsize;
    struct Map *new_struct = calloc(n,sizeof(*new_struct));
    new_struct[0] = ptr[0];
    for(i = 1; i < n; i++){
        if(ptr[j].value != ptr[i].value){
            j++;
            new_struct[j].value = ptr[i].value;
            new_struct[j].position = ptr[i].position;
        }
    }
    newsize = j+1;
    //new_struct = realloc(new_struct, newsize);

    printf("\nSorting in the function:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < newsize; i++){
        printf("%d : %d\n", new_struct[i].value, new_struct[i].position);
    }
    return new_struct;
}
```

In the remove_duplicates() function, I am expecting this as my outcome:

```
-3 : 3
1 : 9
3 : 2
4 : 1
5 : 4
7 : 6
25 : 0
88 : 7
```

However, I am getting an extra key-value 5:5 that is not being removed as such:

```
-3 : 3
1 : 9
3 : 2
4 : 1
5 : 4
5 : 5
7 : 6
25 : 0
88 : 7
```

I tried to loop through it by hand, and I think I'm making a mistake with the j++ because it seems when the conditional is false (i.e there is a duplicate), i iterates while j stays behind, and I think this may be why I'm getting the duplicate 4 removed but not the duplicate 5.

Where am I going wrong? I also feel weird about hard-coding the value at index 0, but obviously the first value isn't one I want to remove (only subsequent values that are duplicates need to be removed), and since i starts at 1, it doesn't get compared.

Lastly, the remove_duplicate() function returns a struct * type. When I print from the main, I get the following output:

```
-3 : 3
1 : 9
3 : 2
4 : 1
5 : 4
5 : 5
7 : 6
25 : 0
```

The last value is not pointed to for some reason. I would like my remove function to be accessible from the main, as I want to pass the pointer p2 to another function that sorts by values in the key-value pairing.  What's happening to my last value?

**EDIT WITH INPUT AND EXPECTED OUTPUT**

The input is an array of int values, that I convert into a struct of value, position. So for instance input is [25,4,3,-3,5,5,7,88,4,1], the struct that is created is:

```
 25 : 0
 4 : 1
 3 : 2
-3 : 3
 5 : 4
 5 : 5
 7 : 6
88 : 7
 4 : 8
 1 : 9
```

My code sorts the values by the value field of the struct, then that removes any duplicate key-value pairings. So an expected outcome would be:

```
-3 : 3
 1 : 9
 3 : 2
 4 : 1
 5 : 4
 7 : 6
25 : 0
88 : 7
```

Where the duplicate pairs (4,8) and (5,5) are removed.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "remove"? Can you provide an example of an input and your expected output?

Comment: Editing post with input and expected output.

Comment: The problem lies here: `if(ptr[j].value != ptr[i].value)`. Just step through it with a smaller set (e.g. 4 4 5 5) and you'll quickly see what's going on. The fix is easy so I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: In case you are wondering why the final output of the program always counts 8 rows, that's caused by `sizeof(*p2)`.

Answer (score -1):

Is this your expected output

```
Struct before sorting:
25 : 0
4 : 1
3 : 2
-3 : 3
5 : 4
5 : 5
7 : 6
88 : 7
4 : 8
1 : 9
Struct after sorting
-3 : 3
1 : 9
3 : 2
4 : 1
4 : 8
5 : 4
5 : 5
7 : 6
25 : 0
88 : 7

Sorting in the function:
-3 : 3
1 : 9
3 : 2
4 : 1
5 : 4
7 : 6
25 : 0
88 : 7

Struct after removing in the main
-3 : 3
1 : 9
3 : 2
4 : 1
5 : 4
7 : 6
25 : 0
88 : 7
```

Just change your if condition from if(ptr[j].value != ptr[i].value) to if(new_struct[j].value != ptr[i].value) in remove_duplicate().

Comment: that's exactly what I want. I was trying to point out that not only was it not removing properly in the remove_duplicate() function, but it wasn't working properly AND it was working differently (not printing the last struct) in the main function. It should work the same in both functions. I need that pointer returned properly to main so I can pass it to a different function later.

Comment: Please, how does this answer the question?

Comment: Just change your if condition from if(ptr[j].value != ptr[i].value) to if(new_struct[j].value != ptr[i].value) in remove_duplicate().

Comment: Never mind. I don't know what I'm talking about. That worked.